# Collectd write_graphite plugin encrypt data

Tags: graphite, collectd

How to configure SSL or Encrypt data using write_graphite plugin

```
LoadPlugin "write_graphite"
<Plugin "write_graphite">
 <Node "example">
   Host "localhost"
   Port "2003"
   #Prefix "collectd."
   #Postfix ""
   #Protocol "udp"
   #LogSendErrors false
   EscapeCharacter "_"
   SeparateInstances true
   StoreRates false
   AlwaysAppendDS false
 </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The write_graphite plugin doesn't do encryption.

If you want the data to be encrypted, the easiest way is to also run collectd on your graphite server, and use collectd's network plugin to encrypt the traffic.

The remote host won't need the write_graphite plugin at all.  The collectd instance on the graphite server needs both the network (as a server) and write_graphite plugins configured.